# How do I separate name and sum of numbers?

Tags: python, file, printing, process

I'm struggling to add those numbers together and put names apart.
So, I need to print each line containing names and total numbers.

e.g.  `Peter Jones: 155`

File 'test1.txt' example:

```
Marshall Rogers, 88, 21, 90
Richard Lao, 30
Peter Jones, 23, 54,78
AABB CC EE RR rest, 90, 3, 3, 4
```

Here's my code:

```
def find_their_numbers(files):
    """print it out"""
    file = open(files)
    lines = file.read().splitlines()
    nam = ""
    new_list = []
    for name in lines:
        names = name.split(',')
        for i in range(len(names)):
            if i == 0:
                print(names[i] + ':', end='')
            if i > 0:
                print(names[i])
find_their_numbers('test1.txt')
```

Comment: First of all, where are you storing the scores? Second of all, what is `print_total_scores()`?

Comment: when you split the lines convert list names into integer excluding the index zero as it your Player Name and then simply add them.

Comment: and their is more better way do it if you are having txt file, simply use pandas dataframe to import your data into it and simply do a column addition.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that without finding individually each number:

```
def find_their_numbers(text_file):
    with open(text_file) as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
        for line in lines:
            line_split = line.split(',')
            name = line_split[0]
            total = sum([int(x) for x in line_split[1:]])
            print(name + ": " + str(total))
```

Sample test:

```
>>> find_their_numbers('test1.txt')
rshall Rogers: 199
Richard Lao: 30
Peter Jones: 155
AABB CC EE RR rest: 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
file = open(files)
lines = file.read().splitlines()
for name in lines:
    names = name.split(',')
    print(f"{names[0]}: {sum(map(int,names[1:]))}")
```

where `sum(map(int,names[1:]))` will slice `names` from the second element, convert all the elements to integers and sum them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use unpacking to separate the name from the rest of the components:

```
with open(fileName,'r') as file:
    for line in file.readLines():
        name,*numbers = line.split(',')
        print(name + ":", sum(map(int,numbers)))
```